# Will frequent charging shorten battery life?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, battery, charging

I purchased a Nokia Wireless Charging Plate DT-900 for my Nokia Lumia 920.

If I place my Lumia on the charging plate all night every night and every time I put it down not using it, even if the battery still has most of it's charge (e.g. 80% or more), will this do anything to shorten the battery life?

I know some types of batteries for other tech items only accept a certain number of recharges. So I'm wondering if using the plate all the time is not recommended and if I should put my phone on the plate or otherwise charge my phone only when the battery is low.

Answer (score 7):

> Some people say that it is better to charge the battery of any mobile
>   device after it is fully drained. But, this is applicable to nickel
>   cadmium types and when it comes to lithium ion, it is not necessary to
>   fully discharge the battery before charging it. This is because when
>   the charge reduces too much, it might cause damage to the device.

Article Source: http://EzineArticles.com/7295341

Lithium ion batteries (The kind used in all modern cell phones) do have lifetime rating in charge cycles, but you do not "use up" a charge cycle by charging too early, merely the portion of a charge cycle. Like the article states, li-on batteries are pretty durable as long as you keep them cool and prevent over-drainage.